# Meaning of the numbers in a sequence definition

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

> The sequence $(a_n)$ tends to $+ \infty \iff$ given any number $C$, there's a number $N$ such that $n > N \implies a_n \ge C.$

Given a certain $N$ it's not difficult to prove the implication, but what's the meaning of $n, N, C$? Do they stand for something concrete other than being numbers(all real?)?

Comment: Their meaning is jointly determined by the context in which they all appear, namely this definition. $C$ might mean "$C$ould there be a subsequence that tends to some number below $C$?" and $N$ might mean "$N$ope, none of the terms after $N$ are less than $C$". $n$ simply points to one of the terms in the sequence.

Comment: I want to slightly reword what you said to check if I actually understand you. You are saying past the term $a_N$, no terms $a_n$ are less than the term $C$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n$ and $N$ are *natural* numbers and are the index of the terms $a_n$ of the *sequence*.

The definition says that for any $C$ you can find a "suitable" $N$ such that from the "term" $a_N$ of the sequence on (this means: $n > N$), all the terms $a_n$  are greater-or-equal to $C$.

Comment: Consider the sequence $s = a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4,\ldots$. Then $1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots$ index the elements of $s$. Also, one of $1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots$ can be chosen to be $N$ and $C$ is one of $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, \ldots.$ Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: @user322231 - yes for the index... and $N$ is one of them, suitably chosen. If e.g. $(a_n)$ is the sequence $2,4,6,8,\ldots$, with $C=10.5$ we have to chose $N=5$ and thus for all $n > N$, i.e. for $a_6=12, a_7=14$ and so one, it is verified that $a_n > C$.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq1}$ is given term for term, and there is nothing arbitrary about that. The numbers $C$ and $N$ however appearing in the definition of the statement $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\infty$ are "arbitrary", in other words: $C$ and $N$  serve only as variable names for a certain logical implication.

We want to express the idea that "for large $n$ all $a_n$ are really large" in a logically stringent way, and saying that for any $C$ however large it is guaranteed that $a_n>C$ as soon as $n$ is large enough, i.e., larger than some $N=N(C)$, is the definitive way of formulating our intended meaning.

Answer (score 0):

One can think of a series that "tends to infinity" in the following way:

for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $a_n> x$. This just means the sequence gets as big as we want it to *eventually*. But sequences in some sense don't have to diverge in one particular way. We often conceive of them as monotone/ always increasing, but this is just some bias we have. For example, if you take the sequence defined by

$ a_n = \begin{cases} 
      \ n  \textrm{ if $n$ is odd} \\
       \ 0  \textrm{ otherwise} \\
   \end{cases}$

This of course doesn't "tend to infinity" in the usual sense of the word, but it is true that for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we can find some $N$ so that $a_n$ is bigger than it. Here, the sequence indeed **diverges** to infinity.

Logically: $\{a_n\}$ diverges to $\infty_+$  $\iff$ $(\forall x \in \mathbb{R})(\exists N \in \mathbb{N})(a_N>x)$

More technically, we can think of a sequence in the reals as follows:

$f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $\{a_n\}$ denotes the set $\{f(1), f(2),...\}$ in the usual ordering.

Then, on a cartesian plane, take any function $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ and just look at the x-values for $x \in \mathbb{N}$, and consider the restriction of $f$ to these values.

Notice that the domain here matters.

So, I guess the take away is that diverging to infinity is certainly something specific, and there are some different ways of thinking about it. The important part to me, is that it only talks about what happens eventually. A sequence can be $a_i=0$ for all $i \leq 10^{10}$, and then start increasing in increments of $10^{-10}$-- but it will still "tend to infinity" (it will also be monotone! even this is well-behaved.)

Comment: Please let me know if this was the kind of answer you were looking for.

Comment: Andres, not exactly, but your answer contains a lot of great info I didn't know. Very much appreciated. Thank you.